# Formula for time taken to pay off loan with annual interest and monthly repayments

Tags: loans, calculation, interest, amortization

I am trying to find how to work out the period of time it will take to pay off a loan. There are plenty of online calculators out there but I cannot find the formula they use. I want to recreate the formulas in excel.

I have found [this site](https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/articles/finance/compound-interest-formula.php) which gives variations of the compound interest formula. It states

> In order to work out calculations involving monthly additions, you will need to use two formulae - our original one, listed above, plus the 'future value of a series' formula for the monthly additions.

Giving the formulas (for contributions at the end of a month) as;

Compound interest for principal:

```
P(1+r/n)^(nt)
```

Future value of a series:

```
PMT × (((1 + r/n)^(nt) - 1) / (r/n))
```

Total:

```
(P(1+r/n)^(nt)) + (PMT × (((1 + r/n)^(nt) - 1) / (r/n)))
```

Where

```
A   =  the future value of the investment/loan, including interest
P   =  the principal investment amount (the initial deposit or loan amount)
PMT =  the monthly payment
r   =  the annual interest rate (decimal)
n   =  the number of times that interest is compounded per unit t
t   =  the time (months, years, etc) the money is invested or borrowed for
```

I have the principle, the annual interest rate and the monthly payment. I assume `n`, the number of times that the interest is compounded is 12, for months in the year (online calculators seem to support this).

I worked out the 'future debt' using this formula and if I manually change the time, I can tell that for example;

```
P   = -20000
r   = 1.1
PMT = 400
```

that the time `t` to pay off the loan would be roughly 4 years, 3 months (4.25).

However, this is pretty fiddly having to change the time in two places in the formula and 'eyeballing' when the future debt (total) is close to zero.

I believe I would like a variation of the total formula above to be something like

```
t = ...
```

Can someone rearrange the formula for this? (or provide the correct one)

I have [checked](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/48775/what-is-the-formula-for-loan-payoff-with-daily-compounded-interest-and-monthly-p) a [number](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/54757/loan-repayment-calculation-and-monthly-compounding-interest-problem) of [questions](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/97063/what-is-the-formula-for-loan-payoff-with-daily-compounded-interest-and-annual-pa) but most just want to find out the future value using a fixed time.

Comment: (This is why you learn Algebra in high school.)

Comment: To compute the number of periods needed to pay off a loan, given an interest rate,  payment amount, starting balance and ending balance, use the `=NPER()` function.

Comment: Perhaps this answer will help : [What is the formula for loan payoff date?](https://money.stackexchange.com/a/102581/11768)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your formula ("*Compound interest for principal*"), `P(1+r/n)^(nt)` - it is implied that `r` is a nominal interest rate compounded according to the frequency `n` per annum.  So a specific [nominal rate for the particular compounding frequency](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Effective_interest_rate#Calculation), rather than an effective annual rate.

The future value of a series with deposits made at the *end* of each period is obtained by summing multiple versions of the above formula (with `PMT` instead of `P`):

[image]

The formula for a loan with payments at the *end* of each period can be obtained similarly.  Instead of compounding forward to a future value it discounts the payments back to the present (initial) value of the loan: `s`.  This formula can be expressed for `t`, the number of years to pay off the loan:

[image]

For example, with 1.1% nominal interest compounded monthly

```
s = 20000
r = 0.011
n = 12
PMT = 400

∴ t = -(Log[1 - (r s)/(n PMT)]/(n Log[(n + r)/n])) = 4.26713 years
```

Also in Excel, as suggested by RonJohn, documented [here](https://exceljet.net/excel-functions/excel-nper-function), the same result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you, in libreoffice calc the formula is `=NPER(C6/12,C7,-C5,,0)`